# Unable to capture faces "y is not defined"

Tags: python, raspicam, opencv

I tried removing `gray[y:y+h,x:x+w] in imwrite` line and the code works amazing but as soon as I add this `[y:y+h,x:x+w]` it says: `y is not defined`. I just don't understand how can this error message!!!

```python
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray

from picamera import PiCamera

import cv2

import time

Id=raw_input('enter your id')

sampleNum=0

camera = PiCamera()

camera.resolution = (320, 240)

camera.framerate = 30

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))

display_window = cv2.namedWindow("Faces")

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/FR22/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

time.sleep(1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

image = frame.array

#FACE DETECTION STUFF
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
sampleNum=sampleNum+1
#DISPLAY TO WINDOW
cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
cv2.imshow("Faces", image)
key = cv2.waitKey(1)

rawCapture.truncate(0)

if key == 27:
    camera.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif sampleNum>20:
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Any good reasons why you reverted my edit to *improve* your code formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y` is out of scope after leaving the `for`-loop which is why you get the `not defined` error with your imwrite. Check your intented program flow and indentation.

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

# x, y, w, h are out of scope here    

sampleNum=sampleNum+1
#DISPLAY TO WINDOW
cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```